# How long does a context switch take in Linux?

Tags: linux

I would like to know approximately how long a context switch time in Linux would take?

Comment: [What is the overhead of a context-switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887797/995714)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get a meaningful number independent of the hardware you're referring to.  [This has been covered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513692/how-long-does-a-context-switch-take-in-linux), and the answers there provide methods to measure this on your machines.